# SQL Query that sums two types of payments for each customer if the processed date is within the effective and expiration date of the customer

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

I have a table with two types of payments:

**Payment_Type_1** and **Payment_Type_2**

The payments are made on a certain date:

**Date_Processed**

The payments are tied to Customer ID's, and each customer ID is effective within a certain date range:

**Customer_ID**, **ID_Effective_Date**, and **ID_Expiration_Date**

I'm attempting to write a query that sums Payment_Type_1 and Payment_Type_2 for each Customer_ID if the Date_Processed is within the ID_Effective_Date and ID_Expiration_Date of the Customer_ID, if the ID_Effective_Date is >=

For example, I have this data:

| Payment_Type_1 | Payment_Type_2 | Customer_ID | ID_Effective_Date | ID_Expiration_Date | Date_Processed |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3357 | 598 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 1/14/2015 |
| 502 | 1242 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 4/24/2018 |
| 3841 | 2972 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 5/12/2018 |
| 461 | 3412 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 5/19/2015 |
| 3106 | 3459 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 5/27/2015 |
| 4112 | 5196 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 5/29/2016 |
| 4035 | 1631 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 | 6/8/2015 |
| 304 | 1382 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 | 6/11/2015 |
| 372 | 4330 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 | 6/15/2015 |
| 1561 | 1817 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 | 6/16/2015 |
| 4745 | 1958 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 | 6/24/2016 |
| 211 | 1586 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 | 7/28/2015 |
| 2141 | 167 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 8/4/2015 |
| 13 | 5008 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 8/11/2017 |
| 2388 | 2002 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 8/13/2017 |
| 4422 | 589 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 8/27/2015 |
| 2542 | 1287 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 9/18/2015 |
| 2162 | 3272 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 | 10/6/2015 |
| 423 | 2418 | 6351859 | 8/1/2015 | 8/1/2016 | 11/19/2016 |
| 649 | 2032 | 6351859 | 8/1/2015 | 8/1/2016 | 11/24/2015 |
| 2316 | 195 | 6351859 | 8/1/2015 | 8/1/2016 | 11/28/2015 |
| 3675 | 3783 | 6351859 | 8/1/2016 | 8/1/2017 | 12/10/2016 |
| 234 | 3214 | 6351859 | 8/1/2016 | 8/1/2017 | 12/13/2015 |
| 2817 | 1563 | 6351859 | 8/1/2016 | 8/1/2017 | 12/14/2015 |
| 3391 | 5723 | 6351859 | 8/1/2016 | 8/1/2017 | 12/15/2017 |
| 4569 | 3802 | 6351859 | 8/1/2017 | 8/1/2018 | 12/16/2017 |
| 5268 | 3045 | 6351859 | 8/1/2017 | 8/1/2018 | 1/7/2018 |

And I'd like the output to be like this:

| Payment_Type_1 | Payment_Type_2 | Customer_ID | ID_Effective_Date | ID_Expiration_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24674 | 23530 | 55989 | 2/1/2015 | 2/1/2016 |
| 8857 | 7154 | 55989 | 2/1/2016 | 2/1/2017 |
| 2401 | 7010 | 55989 | 2/1/2017 | 2/1/2018 |
| 4343 | 4214 | 55989 | 2/1/2018 | 2/1/2019 |
| 6016 | 7004 | 6351859 | 8/1/2015 | 8/1/2016 |
| 4098 | 6201 | 6351859 | 8/1/2016 | 8/1/2017 |
| 13228 | 12570 | 6351859 | 8/1/2017 | 8/1/2018 |

I have the following query, but it's not generating the results I'm looking for:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentTypeID = 11 THEN Payment_Amount ELSE 0 END) AS Payment_Type_1,
    SUM(CASE WHEN PaymentTypeID = 12 THEN Payment_Amount else 0 END) AS Payment_Type_2,
    Customer.Customer_ID,
    Customer_Info.ID_Effective_Date,
    Customer_Info.ID_Expiration_Date,
    Date_Processed
FROM dbo.Payment_Table

WHERE Approved = 1
AND ID_Effective_Date >='2015-01-01 00:00:00.000'
GROUP BY Customer_ID, ID_Effective_Date, ID_Expiration_Date, Date_Processed
```

Comment: `AND Date_Processed BETWEEN ID_Effective_Date AND ID_Expiration_Date` ? Your query also doesn't match the sampled data you've provided in the question.

Comment: Thanks @EdwardRadcliffe this is exactly what I was looking for. I'm a student and new to SQL, I appreciate your help!

Comment: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)